# How can i read input only a part of the image without creating another image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, opencv

```
import cv2

fname = '1.png'
img=cv2.imread(fname, 0)
print (img)//the outcome is an array of values from 0 to 255 (grayscale)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
nums, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh, None, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
dst = cv2.convertScaleAbs(255.0*labels/nums)
cv2.imwrite(dest_dir+"output.png", dst)
```

that code works just fine, so i moved on to adjusting my code so it can take a portion of the image not the entire image:

```
from PIL import Image

    img = Image.open(fname)
    img2 = img.crop((int(xmin), int(yMin),int(xMax), int(yMax))
```

xmin ymin xmax ymax simply being the top left bottom right coordinates of the box.
then i did `img = cv2.imread(img2)` to continue as the previous code but got an error, i printed img2 and got `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=54x10 at 0x7F4D283AFB70>` how can i adjust it to be able to input that crop or image portion instead of fname in my code above, and kindly note i don't want to save img2 as an image and carry on from there because i need to work on the main image.

Comment: That's exactly what i said i don't want to do, kindly refer to the last part of my question.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad

Comment: No worries, thanks for the suggestion and would love to hear others if you have a way that'd let me provide that image section in the format i want.

Answer (score 1):

try cv2.imshow() instead of printing it. In order to see an image you cropped, you need to use cv2 function. here is a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks but my main goal isn't seeing the image it's inputting what i cropped instead of `fname` in the fourth line of the code i shared in my question.

Comment: you have that cropped image in img2, what exactly you want to do with it ? can you explain it little more ?

Comment: Sure i cropped a region of interest,  then i will use that region of interest i have and apply `connected components` on it but on the main  image which i shared the code for in my question, so in case the cropped object isn't properly done and there is still connected pixels i'll be able to get them, hope my comment helped.

Comment: no you can not do that. you will have to save that image and pass it to cv2.imread() as a file variable

Comment: is there a way to apply my first code on a region of an image not on the full image? and just saving it won't do me well i need to work on the main image.

Comment: check if this may help http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_inpainting/py_inpainting.html

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **NO** you cannot.

Open up your terminal /IDE and type in `help(cv2.imread)`.

It clearly states that **The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it.** So in order to use `cv2.imread()` you must pass it in as a file **not** an image.

Your best bet would be to save your cropped image as a file and then read it.

Comment: yes i saw that in opencv imread docs too but was hoping for some way around it https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html is there a way to apply my first code on a region of an image not on the full image? and just saving it won't do me well i need to work on the main image.

Comment: you have the cropped image, why not just work on that?

Comment: because the data i have is bad and they're badly cropped, as simple as that so i need to check connected components to the elements i already have in the cropped part.